# VideoJS include time gaps from Kinesis stream

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js, amazon-kinesis

**I want VideoJS to include gaps in the timeline from a Kinesis stream.**

I'm using VideoJS to play an "ON_DEMAND" stream from Kinesis.

Requesting a video from 13:00 to 14:00 may result in a video duration shorter than 1 hour in VideoJS. (For example, 13:15 - 13:50)

Can I manipulate VideoJS to not parse out empty sections? (So the resulting timeline is 13:00 - 14:00, preferably with an indicator that "there is currently no video to display")

(I am attempting to align the video playback with an external timeline.)